# Bounding expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\beta^* \in\mathbb R^p \sim c\exp(-f(\beta))$ be a random variable and  $\beta (\lambda) \in\mathbb R^p \sim c_1\exp(-f(\beta)  - \lambda \|\beta\|_2^2/2)$ be a random variable for some appropriate constant $c$ and $c_1$, and both the random variables are independent of each other. Also, let $E[\|\beta^*\|^2_2] = \alpha$ and $E[\beta^*] = \delta$. Let $f$ be $m$-strongly convex and $L$-lipschitz smooth. I am trying to find a strong uppr bound on expectation of $\|\beta^* - \beta(\lambda) \|^2 $ in terms of $\lambda, \delta, \alpha, L, m$ and $p$-
\begin{align*}
E \left[    \|\beta^* - \beta(\lambda)  \|^2 \right] 
\end{align*}

Comment: When you write $A\sim B$, is $B$ the pdf of $A$?

Comment: @JacobManaker Yes

Comment: How did this problem arise?  Is $m$ small/large/neither relative to $\lambda$?

Comment: @JacobManaker The origin of the problem is a very long story, but it is very loosely related to the regularized and unregularized version of a distribution. $m$ can be anything relative to $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin, we need some connection between $f$ and $(\alpha,\delta)$.  Since $f$ is $m$-strongly convex, it has some minimum, achieved at, say $\beta_0$.  Changing $c_0$ as necessary, I assume $f(\beta_0)=0$.  Moreover, as $\beta$ moves away from $\beta_0$, $f$ grows at least quadratically, and so the corresponding pdf decays *at least* as fast as the normal.  (That's already *very* fast; see Putanumonit's [discussion](https://putanumonit.com/2015/11/10/003-soccer1/), but take his soccer conclusions with a grain of salt.)

Thus we estimate \begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\|\beta^*-\beta_0\|_2^2]&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^p}{\|\beta-\beta_0\|_2^2\cdot c_0e^{-f(\beta)}\,d^p\beta} \\
&\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}^p}{c_0\|\beta-\beta_0\|_2^2e^{-\frac{m}{2}\|\beta-\beta_0\|_2^2}\,d^p\beta} \\
&=c_0\cdot \text{vol}(S^{p-1})\int_0^{\infty}{r^2e^{-\frac{m}{2}r^2}\cdot r^{p-1}\,dr} \\
&=c_0\cdot\frac{2\pi^{\frac{p}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{m}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}\Gamma\left(\frac{p}{2}+1\right) \\
&=\frac{c_0p}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}
\end{align*} where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) function, respectively.  This is small: $\delta$ and $\beta_0$ roughly coincide.

(Essentially, we just performed [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).)

We want to do the same with $\beta(\lambda)$, since then the difference is $$\beta(\lambda)-\beta^*=\beta(\lambda)-\beta_0+\beta_0-\beta^*$$  But the mean is not quite so straightforward: if we approximate $\beta(\lambda)$ as a normal, then it is centered around $\left(\frac{m}{m+2\lambda}\right)\beta_0$: $$\frac{m}{2}\|\beta-\beta_0\|_2^2+\lambda\|\beta\|_2^2=\left(\frac{m}{2}+\lambda\right)\left\|\beta-\left(\frac{m}{m+2\lambda}\right)\beta_0\right\|_2^2+\frac{m}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{m+2\lambda}\right)\|\beta_0\|^2$$ just from completing the square.  As before, I will absorb the constant term into $c_1$, so that our bound is $$\text{pdf}_{\beta(\lambda)}(\beta)\leq c_1e^{-\left(\frac{m}{2}+\lambda\right)\left\|\beta-\frac{m}{m+2\lambda}\beta_0\right\|_2^2}$$

Once I have that estimate, though, the exact same argument goes through: $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left\|\beta-\frac{m}{m+2\lambda}\beta_0\right\|_2^2\right]\leq\frac{c_1p}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi}{m+2\lambda}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}$$

Now, by the identity $$\|a+b+c\|^2\leq3(\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2+\|c\|^2)$$ (true in any inner product space), we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\|\beta^*-\beta(\lambda)\|_2^2]&=\mathbb{E}\left[\left\|\left(\beta^*-\beta_0\right)+\frac{2\lambda}{m+2\lambda}\beta_0+\left(\left(\frac{m}{m+2\lambda}\right)\beta_0-\beta(\lambda)\right)\right\|_2^2\right] \\
&\leq3\left(\mathbb{E}[\|\beta^*-\beta_0\|^2]+\frac{2\lambda}{m+2\lambda}\|\beta_0\|_2^2+\mathbb{E}\left[\left\|\left(\frac{m}{m+2\lambda}\right)\beta_0-\beta(\lambda)\right\|_2^2\right]\right) \\
&\leq3\left(\frac{c_0p}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}+\frac{2\lambda}{m+2\lambda}\|\beta_0\|_2^2+\frac{c_1p}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi}{m+2\lambda}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}\right)
\end{align*}  If you want to sharpen this, you can do a little better with calculating out the cross terms.  But I don't think they'll be leading-order.

In any case, we're almost done.  The only term we haven't computed in terms of our original parameters is $\|\beta_0\|^2$.  Well, \begin{align*}
\|\beta_0\|_2^2-\|\beta^*\|_2^2&=\left|\|\beta^*+(\beta_0-\beta^*)\|_2^2-\|\beta^*\|_2^2\right| \\
&=\left|\|\beta^*-\beta_0\|_2^2+2\langle\beta^*,\beta_0-\beta^*\rangle\right| \\
&\leq\|\beta^*-\beta_0\|_2^2+2\|\beta^*\|_2\|\beta_0-\beta^*\|_2
\end{align*} where the last line is by Cauchy-Schwarz.  Taking expectations, we have $$\|\beta_0\|_2^2-\alpha\leq\frac{c_0p}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}+2\mathbb{E}[\|\beta^*\|_2]\mathbb{E}[\|\beta_0-\beta^*\|_2]$$  Reversing the order of subtraction on the left and repeating the same proof, we can introduce an absolute value: $$\left|\|\beta_0\|_2^2-\alpha\right|\leq\frac{c_0p}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}+2\mathbb{E}[\|\beta^*\|_2]\mathbb{E}[\|\beta_0-\beta^*\|_2]$$  Thus it suffices to show that both terms on the right are small.  By Jensen's inequality, for any random variable $R$, we have $\mathbb{E}[R]^2\leq\mathbb{E}[R^2]$; equivalently, $\mathbb{E}[R]\leq\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[R^2]}$.  Thus $$\left|\|\beta_0\|_2^2-\alpha\right|\leq\frac{c_0p}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}+2\sqrt{\alpha}\sqrt{\frac{c_0p}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}}$$

Putting it all together, \begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\|\beta^*-\beta(\lambda)\|_2^2]&\leq\frac{3p}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}\left(c_0+c_1\left(\frac{m}{m+2\lambda}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}\right)+{} \\
&\qquad\frac{6\lambda}{m+2\lambda}\left(\sqrt{\alpha}+\sqrt{\frac{c_0p}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}+1}}\right)^2
\end{align*}

Comment: This is great! Thanks!