# What does multiplying a pdf mean?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have two (independent) continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ with pdfs $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ respectively.  It is well-known that $f(x)g(x)$ is *not* the pdf of $XY$; in fact, $f(x)g(x)$ may not be a pdf at all (see Appendix).

On the other hand, (assuming $X$ and $Y$ have common support — h/t Thomas Andrews) it's easy enough to make $f(x)g(x)$ a pdf: just rescale by $\left(\int{f(x)g(x)\,dx}\right)^{-1}$.  Then we have the following interesting facts:

- If $f(x)=g(x)=1[0\leq x\leq 1]$ (uniform distribution), then $f(x)g(x)$ is *also* the pdf of the uniform distribution.
- If $f(x)=\lambda_fe^{-\lambda_fx}\cdot1[0\leq x]$, $g(x)=\lambda_ge^{-\lambda_gx}\cdot1[0\leq x]$ (exponential distribution), then $f(x)g(x)\propto(\lambda_f+\lambda_g)e^{-(\lambda_f+\lambda_g)x}\cdot1[0\leq x]$, *also* the pdf of the exponential distribution.
- Same for two normal distributions.
- Multiplying a normal and an exponential gives a normal.
- If $X$ is as in the appendix ($2x1[0\leq x\leq 1]$) and $Y$ is supported on $[0,1]$ with standard deviation $\sigma$, then $f(x)g(x)$ after rescaling has mean $2\sigma^2$.

So clearly there's something going on here.  **Is there a probabilistic interpretation for $f(x)g(x)$?**

---

**Appendix**

For example, let $$f(x)=g(x)=2x\cdot 1[0\leq x\leq1]$$ (where $1[A]$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $A$).  Then $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}{f(x)g(x)\,dx}=\int_0^1{4x^2\,dx}=\frac{4}{3}\neq1$$  Thus $f(x)g(x)$ isn't even a pdf.

For completeness, the law of $XY$ is as follows: \begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[XY\leq x]&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{f(s)\mathbb{P}\left[Y\leq\frac{x}{s}\right]\,ds} \\
&=\int_0^1{2s\min{(1,(x/s)^2)}\,ds} \\
&=\int_0^x{2s\,ds}+\int_x^1{2x/s\,ds} \\
&=x^2-2x\ln{(x)}
\end{align*}  To get the pdf, differentiate; the result is precisely $2(x-\ln{(x)}-1)1[0\leq x\leq1]$.

Comment: You can only rescale if that integral is non-zero. If $X$ is strictly negative, and $Y$ is strictly positive, then $\int f(x)g(x)\,dx=0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Ooh, good point!

Comment: If you consider the simpler discrete probabilities, the product is $$P(X=n\mid X=Y)=\frac{P(X=n\land Y=n)}{P(X=Y)}$$ This assumes that $P(X=Y)\neq 0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: That sounds like the start of an answer to me!

Comment: Yeah, I’m still thinking about how that plays out in the continuous case, since in most continuous cases, $P(X=Y)=0.$

Comment: The natural interpretation is that this the joint distribution of independent $X$ and $Y$, conditioned on the event that $X=Y$.  I’m no probability expert but I understand there are some ways to interpret conditional probability that make sense even for certain zero-probability events.  See for instance this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/450004/30402

Answer (score 3):

Here's one thing I've noticed: **multiplying the pdf multiplies the moment-generating/characteristic function.**  (Sort of.  See below.)

First, recall what the moment generating function (MGF) is: given a random variable $R$, the MGF of $R$ is $$M_R(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{tR}]$$  The name arises from the fact that $M_R$ has Maclaurin series $$M_R(t)=1+\mathbb{E}[R]t+\mathbb{E}[R^2]\frac{t^2}{2}+\dots\qquad t\ll1$$  $M_R$ doesn't always exist (what if $R$ has infinite moments?), but an analogous function, the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) always does; everything I say can be translated to that *mutatis mutandis*.  In any case, the moment generating function *uniquely determines the distribution*.

Now, let $X$ have pdf $f(x)$ and $Z$ pdf $cf(z)g(z)$.  Then we can write down a simple formula for the moment-generating function of $Z$: $$\mathbb{E}[e^{tZ}]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{e^{tz}\cdot cf(z)g(z)\,dz}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{(cg(z)e^{tz})f(z)\,dz}=\mathbb{E}[cg(X)e^{tX}]$$

Comment: I’m not sure I’d say that even sort of “multiplies the moment generating functions.” There’s not much nice about that last expression.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Fair enough.  I wrote this question because I encountered this result solving [a different problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182314/bounding-expectation), where it is useful.